# indices of factor level of vector

Tags: r

How to get vector containing indices of each element in the level attribute of the vector k?  That is how to get vector (1, 2, 1) for the k ?

```
 k <- factor(c('a', 'b', 'a'))
> k
[1] a b a
Levels: a b
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `match`

```
match(k, levels(k))
#[1] 1 2 1
```

Or convert to numeric to get the integer storage values

```
as.integer(k)
[1] 1 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply